# Show that $f$ has infinitely many fixed points

Tags: complex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f:ℂ→ℂ$ be an entire function. Assume that the equation $f(s)=a$ has infinitely many real solutions **for all reals** $a$. Show that $f$ has infinitely many **fixed points**, i.e., there exists infinitely many reals $t$ such that $f(t)=t$.

Comment: $f(z) = i+\sin z$, and $a = i$. There must be some further conditions to make it true.

Comment: I mean $1 + \sin z$ also satisfies that it has infinitely many zeros, but definitely has finitely many fixed points (at least real ones).

Comment: @DanielFischer: The condition is: the equation $f(s)=a$ has infinitely many real solutions **for all reals** $a$.

Comment: @DER : Where did you get this problem?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: It is a self research problem.

Comment: @Der : Well then you know that the statement is false :)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: The condition is: the equation $f(s)=a$ has infinitely many real solutions **for all reals** $a$.

Comment: $f(x) = x\sin(x)/2$ doesn't have many real fixpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still false after your update. Take $$f(z) = \frac12 z \sin z.$$
It is clear that $f(x) = a$ has infinitely many real solutions for every real $a$, but the only real solution to $f(x) = x$ is $x=0$.

Comment: I'm curious : why did you put that $\frac 12$? It didn't help me to see it "clearly"

Comment: @ mrf: I have edited the question.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Without the $\frac12$, there are lots of fixpoints.

Comment: @mrf : Right, didn't think about that. haha! I only thought about the computations in the "proof".